# How to generate a list of String from a String in Kotlin?

Tags: string, kotlin, generate

I'm a beginner in Kotlin, I want to know how to generate a list of String from a string.

```
For example, from a string "**martin**", I want to have a list of string:

m.artin
m.a.rtin
ma.rtin
mar.tin
m.a.r.t.i.n
etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean convert arraylist to string, I really don't understand your question but you can read about Kotlin JoinToString method

Comment: I want from the string "Martin" to generate a list of following string:

M.artin
Ma.rtin
Mar.tin
Mart.in
Marti.n
M.a.r.t.i.n